# Is a main method required for classes?

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I'm reading in places that it's necessary to have a main method in each class like this:

```
public static void main(String args [ ]) { }
```

However, none of my classes in my current project contain such a method, and so far my app experiences no issues...here's one of my classes for reference.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final String[] classes = {"Database"}; // Sets the labels for each button
    private Context mContext;

    public GridAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() { //autogenerated tab, returns length of an array.
    return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    // The position an item is in in an array.
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position]; 
    }

    // Gets the ID of each item in the array.
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    gridView = new View(mContext);
    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridset, null);

    TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
        .findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(classes[position]);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
        .findViewById(R.id.img);

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    } else {
    gridView = convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.img};
}
```

Is it because I'm extending something (in this case BaseAdapter)? Right now the classes that are currently complete and actually function have an extension, So I am wondering if my WIP classes that don't will need a main() method.

Comment: No, it certainly is not necessary to have that in all classes; it is only necessary in classes which are the entry point for running your application. Where have you read this?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Nope. `public static void main(String args[])` isn't required in Android at all.

Comment: @Alex https://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html

Comment: First sentence is: "In Java, you need to have a method named main in at least one class. " at least one, not all.

Comment: "In *Java*, you need to have a method named main in *at least one* class" - They mean a) desktop Java and b) don't  say 'each class'. In Android you want 0 of them because there is already a hidden one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference reads "in at least one class" and pertains to a standalone Java SE program. 
In Android you, however, do not need `main` at all. Your Activities will be brought to life by Android OS calling **callbacks** into your Activities such as [`onCreate`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)), [`onPause`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) etc...